# Magento2 bundle product retail price would like to display

Tags: magento2, price, bundle

I would like to fetch and display **bundle product** sales price on the PDP page in the custom block programmatically (what ever the default options selected)

Can any one advise me the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this code**

```
$productId = 46; //any bundle product id
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
//get all the selection products used in bundle product.
$selectionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
    ->getSelectionsCollection(
        $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product),
        $product
    );
$priceHelper = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data'); // Instance of Pricing Helper
$final_price = 0;
foreach ($selectionCollection as $proselection) {
    $selectionArray = [];
    //print_r($proselection->getData());

    if ($proselection->getIsDefault()) {
        echo $proselection->getName();
        echo '-> ';
        $formattedCurrencyValue = $priceHelper->currency($proselection->getPrice(), true, false);
        echo $formattedCurrencyValue;
        echo '<br>';
        $final_price = $final_price + $proselection->getPrice();
    }
}
$formattedCurrencyValue = $priceHelper->currency($final_price, true, false);
echo "<br/>Final Price Is " . $formattedCurrencyValue;
```